# Make flash file scale to div width and maintain height according to its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, flash, height, swfobject

We're having a problem to make a flash file scale 100% according to the parent div width, while still maintaining the height according to its aspect ratio.

Please check out the code on jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/LgegF) or paste the below code into an empty html-page:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.diescon.net/yellowfestival/400x400.swf", "flash-content", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", '', null, {wmode: 'transparent'});
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #container {
            width: 400px; /* Fixed width according to page template */
            height: auto; /* Container height should adapt to the content, we do not want to set a fixed height here */
            background-color: pink; /* Background of container */
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        #flash-content {
            width: 400px; /* Fill the width of the parent, could be fixed but ideally 100% */
            height: 100%; /* We want the height of the flash object/flash content to scale according to the aspect ratio of the swf, we do not want to set a fixed height here */
        }

        /* This is what we really want */
        #what-we {
            width: 400px;
            height: auto;
            background-color: pink;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        #really-want {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px; /* This is what we really want, but without setting this height fixed */
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="flash-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="what-we">
        <div id="really-want">
            <span>This is what we really want</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem and I find this page that was very useful:
http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Based on what I've learn on this article, I propose to change your HTML code to:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
        <div id="flash-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And to change your CSS code by adding:

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100%;  /* 1:1 */
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper object, .videoWrapper embed, {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can see the result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LgegF/56/

Hope this help.

PatBriPerso

Answer (score 0):

It appears what you are looking for is

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Let me know how that works out.

-Brian

Comment: I've already tried all those combinations, nothing seems to work :-( I suspect that I need some JS to retrieve the height, maybe by using a wrapper-swf with getters that i can call, but ideally I'd like to solve it without any of this.

Answer (score 0):

Ommit the css height declaration for the flash container alltogether. Swf's usually do scale (or you can set their scale behaviour in your embed/swfobject options), so if you just restrict the width, the height of the swf itself scales accordingly.

[edit:]
Working fiddle (with very rudimentary swf embed code): http://jsfiddle.net/LgegF/1/
You notice how the swf scales when scaling the browser. The white on top and bottom of the swf is due to the object inclusion, swfobject or the  tags give you controll over how the swf itself scales (scale mode, align, valign, etc). What you notice though, is how the swf uses the container's width to determine its size, i.e. fitting the width and scaling the height accordingly.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Please use the fiddle and try it yourself. I'll take a look at the scaling properties that can be set.

Comment: First of all, your fiddle doesn't work, separate css and js and don't wrap in html/body tags. Second, the swf will scale, the wrapper won't, because it has no way of knowing what is the swf's size at whatever scale mode. I update my answer with a working fiddle to illustrate.

Comment: My fiddle works just fine, although it's not separated :-) Your solution is not an answer to my problem statement. We cannot set a fixed height on the container...

Comment: "We're having a problem to make a flash file scale 100% according to the parent div width, while still maintaining the height according to its aspect ratio." The swf does scale - the css does not. If you need the wrapper to "css-scale" according to the current size (i.e. height) of the swf, you might have to use javascript.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to get it all in the title. I wrote in the CSS comments that the container height should not be fixed. This particular flash will be displayed in the site's content area, which has a flexible height. But I think you're right, we need JS here, although I'm still searching for any solution.